# Two way binding and listener in angulardart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Angular dart support two way binding using the [(ngModel)] notation.
I would like to use it, but to also have a callback be called after the update.

Currently, what I have is the following:

```
  String get invoiceNum => dossier.invoiceNum;
  set invoiceNum(String value) {
    dossier.invoiceNum = value;
    _dossierChanged();
  }
```

and in my template:

```
<material-input [(ngModel)]="invoiceNum"></material-input>
```

But this seems like a lot of boilerplate, when all I want is to add a callback to ngModelChange.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
<material-input [(ngModel)]="invoiceNum" (ngModelChange)="dossierChange($event)"></material-input>
```

(`dossierChange` can't be private in this case)